# Tips for golfing in Processing

Tags: code-golf, tips

Does anyone have any [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) tips for golfing in [Processing](http://processing.org)? It is a graphical extension of java, and is somewhat difficult to golf.

Comment: Nice question. I believe tips should be on Community Wiki. I flagged it for migration.

Comment: Downvote??? why?

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote... you'll lose all the rep you got from this post after it is marked as community wiki anyway...

Comment: @ace: Reputation gained before a post is marked CW will be kept: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/229438

Answer (score 8):

- If no animation is required, you can skip the `void draw()` and put everything into `void setup()`.
- Initialising the size of the canvas is sometimes not necessary - it will be initialised to `(100, 100)` by default.
- If you need to use `height` and `width` in your code, it is usually shorter to use their numeric values instead. For example, with a canvas of size `(100, 100)`, using `99` to replace `height` and `width` can save you 7 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

If you only run code in the setup method then you don't need write the method outline. For example you can write:

```
rect(10,10,90,90);
```

instead of

```
void setup {
    rect(10,10,90,90);
}
```

And as long as you don't use any other methods then everything will be put in the setup method before running

Comment: This can be a bit buggy. I've noticed that if you try to define a function in static mode, Processing can get a bit confused: https://puu.sh/tpzP8.png

Comment: @quat as long as you don't define any other methods then everything will be put in the setup method. If you need to define methods then you'll need to explicitly name the setup method.

Answer (score 3):

## White `#FFFFFF`

<sup>Related: [Colour Notation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101955/41805)</sup>

Instead of using this for white:

```
color(255)     //10 bytes
```

you can do this:

```
color(-1)      //9 bytes
```

and save 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

## Colours `(R, G, B)` notation

#### Hexadecimal colours

Processing is very flexible in colour format.

```
fill(255,255,0); //16 bytes
```

can be written using hexadecimal notation as

```
fill(#ffff00);   //14 bytes (2 bytes saved)
```

#### Grayscale

Here is a special usage for colours if all the Red, Green and the Blue values are the same (white):

```
fill(255,255,255); //18 bytes
fill(#ffffff);     //14 bytes
fill(255);         //10 bytes
```

All the three parameters can be shortened into one parameter containing the grayscale value: from `0` black to `255` white.

This can be extended for alpha as well:

```
fill(175,175,175,50); //translucent gray
fill(175,50);         //8 bytes shorter
```

Both mean the same colour, but the latter way is shorter by 8 bytes.

#### Alpha

Although obvious, it should be stated that the alpha parameter in specifying colours is optional since colours are defaulted to an alpha value of `255` (100% opaque).

## Summary: Color formats

Use the shortest colour format to express your colour (remember to leave out unnecessary bits -depending on the context of the program- for example: alpha or grayscale)

`R`: Red
`G`: green
`B`: blue
`A`: alpha
`g`: grayscale

```
RRR,GGG,BBB
#RRGGBB
ggg
RRR,GGG,BBB,AAA
ggg,AAA
```

Answer (score 2):

### Abbreviate constants

If you're ever using one of the all-caps keywords in Processing (such as `DIFFERENCE` or `TRIANGLE_FAN`), see if the number they correspond to is shorter.

For example, `DIFFERENCE` is just an `int` that's equal to 32. Instead of using `DIFFERENCE` [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/107082/34793), I could write `32`, saving 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

## Shorter alternative to `void keyPressed(){}`

```processing
void draw(){}void keyPressed(){foo;} //36 bytes
void draw(){if(key>0)foo;}           //26 bytes
```

The `void draw(){}` is needed by default in order for `key` to be updated. If the user hasn't pressed a key since the start of the program, `key` is given a value of `0`. By checking if it is more than `0` (ie the user has pressed a key), we have golfier code and save 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Setting and committing pixels using set()

It's more efficient to set pixels via [pixels[]](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html):

```
pixels[0] = color(255)
updatePixels();
```

However, that requires `updatePixels()` and also using an index which depending on the scenario will require converting an x,y position to a pixel index.
To keep things short, even though it's less CPU efficient (as each call updates the whole buffer), [set()](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html) allows a pixel to set and committed to buffer straight away in one call.

```
set(0,0,color(255));
```